# Stack snippets above a linked answer push the answer out of view

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

Not sure how butt-burningly important this is but I've noticed that if you click on a linked answer such as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48286752/2191572) then the Stack Snippeted answers above the linked answer end up pushing the linked answer out of focus/sight.

I know that the linked answer is briefly highlighted but that can easily be missed if one gets distracted.

I am using Windows 7 x64 FireFox x64 57.0.4

Just wondering about the possibilities of an elegant solution.

Maybe something like:

```
if(
    every time a stack-snippet has loaded &&
    user has linked answer within viewport
){
    // Keep answer within viewport auto-magically
}
else{
    // Do nothing I guess?
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when navigating to that link the stack snippet in the answer above it pushes the linked answer downwards rather than the linked answer being in line with the top of the screen? If so, I couldn't replicate this in any way using Chrome 63.0.3239.132

Comment: please provide your setup: OS browser etc... as I can't see any issues on Win10 Chrome latest either.

Comment: Seems to be only an issue in Firefox, replicated with Firefox ESR 52.5.3 (64-Bit) (Win10).

Comment: @NickA I've added my OS and browser info. Seems to only be a FireFox issue. Additionally, your re-phrasing of the problem is correct.

Comment: @Tanner I've added the info.

Comment: "Just wondering about the possibilities of an elegant solution." Enter [scroll anchoring](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scroll-anchoring).

Comment: @BoltClock Exciting. Can us mere mortals use it?

Comment: Unable to replicate, Windows 10, Chrome 63.0.3239.132.

Comment: @cybermonkey Thanks, try FireFox.

Comment: Firefox 57.0.4 on Win 10 has the snippets push the linked answer down, then a second later, the orange "this is where you were linked" flash happens, and Firefox recenters on the question (as expected/desired). The flickering is annoying, but I do end up where I want to go.

Comment: ["If you're doing a text search in this document for the word 'butts,' the good news is that it's here, but the bad news is that it only appears in this unrelated quote." - Randall Munroe](https://xkcd.com/1942/)